# Dynamically generating elements in a Grid through MVVM UWP

Tags: mvvm, uwp, dynamically-generated

I am trying to dynamically generate items in a grid using ItemsControl. I want the grid to have only one row and 2*(number of elements) columns so the space between elements can be equal. The items should obtain all available horizontal space in the container and between them should be a thick line.
I bind the container that should held the items in code-behind of the page:

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MainViewModel)this.DataContext).Container = this.FindName("algContainer") as Grid;
    }
```

The view model for each item is:

```
public class ElementViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private int _column;
    private double _width;
    private double _height;
    private double _strokeTickness;
    private Brush _fill;
    private SolidColorBrush _stroke;
    private VerticalAlignment _verticalAlignment;

    public ElementViewModel()
    {

    }

    public double Width
    {
        get { return _width; }
        set
        {
            _width = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public double Height
    {
        get { return _height; }
        set
        {
            _height = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Brush Fill
    {
        get { return _fill; }
        set
        {
            _fill = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public VerticalAlignment VerticalAlignment
    {
        get { return _verticalAlignment; }
        set
        {
            _verticalAlignment = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public double StrokeThickness
    {
        get { return _strokeTickness; }
        set
        {
            _strokeTickness = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public SolidColorBrush Stroke
    {
        get { return _stroke; }
        set
        {
            _stroke = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Column
    {
        get { return _column; }
        set
        {
            _column = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The method that generate the elements is in the page view model:

```
public ICommand Sort
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._sortCommand == null)
            {
                this._sortCommand = new RelayCommand(this.PerformSort);
            }
            return this._sortCommand;
        }

    }

private void PerformSort()
    {
        this.ElementCollection = PopulateElements();
    }

private List<ElementViewModel> PopulateElements()
    {
        var heightsList = GenerateRadnomNumbers(this.ElementsCount, (int)this.Container.ActualHeight);
        double width = this.Container.ActualWidth / this.ElementsCount;
        var collection = new List<ElementViewModel>();

        this.Container.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
        this.Container.Children.Clear();

        for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < this.ElementsCount; i++, j += 2)
        {
            var emptyColDef = new ColumnDefinition();
            var elementColDef = new ColumnDefinition();
            var element = new ElementViewModel();

            emptyColDef.Width = GridLength.Auto;
            elementColDef.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);

            this.Container.ColumnDefinitions.Add(emptyColDef);
            this.Container.ColumnDefinitions.Add(elementColDef);

            element.Width = width;
            element.Height = heightsList[i];
            element.Column = j;
            element.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            element.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            element.StrokeThickness = 1;
            element.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;

            collection.Add(element);
        }

        return collection;
    }
```

The XAML I want to populate is:

```
<Grid  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Margin="12">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementCollection, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="algContainer" Background="White"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Fill="{Binding Fill}" StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}" Stroke="{Binding Stroke}" Grid.Column="{Binding Column}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
<Border Margin="12"  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0">
            <Button x:Name="sortButton" Content="Sort" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="80" Command="{Binding Sort}"/>
        </Border>
```

Everything works but elements (rectangles) are placed in one column with many rows but I want them to be in one row with many columns. Is the problem in the ItemsControl and how should I change it?

Comment: `((MainViewModel)this.DataContext).Container = this.FindName("algContainer") as Grid;` that's not MVVM.  You should be using DataTemplates.  If you don't know what they are or how they are used, go research that now.  If your needs are too complex for data templating alone, create a user control and encapsulate your UI work within it.  Expose public dependency properties on it and bind those to your view model (or whatever properties the view model has that contain what you need to put in the grid).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a horizontal `ItemsPanel`, like this:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsStackPanel
                Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

I think you have a small confusion between `ViewModel`s and `Model`s. The `ElementViewModel` is just a normal `Model` in my eyes (as it only provides data and no commands), so I would extend from the `ObservableObject` (which `MVVM light` already provides), and rename it to `ElementModel`. You are already using it correctly as far as I can tell, it's just the naming.

Comment: When I use something like StackPanel calculation for width of every item is somehow wrong. I tried several ways to calculate it but every time elements obtain more or less of the container's horizontal space.

Comment: the `StackPanel` always expands to surround its content. you can take the width of your `<Grid>` as the actual width you want to use (the "full width"), and base your calculation on that (because the `Grid` expands to fit the width of its parent)